meaning of $IBr(X | Q)$
In the paper 1, there is a notation used without specifying the meaning.
It is $IBr(X | Q)$ in Definition $4.1$. What it means? Irreducible Brauer characters of the group X from a block with defect group $Q$? I tried to deduce the meaning from the proof. Didn't succeed.
Also, I see the following: for $Q$ a radical subgroup of $G$, there exists a subset $IBr(b|Q)$ of $IBr(b)$ .... What does $IBr(b|Q)$ mean? They didn't specify. $b$ is a block of $G$ here.

The meaning of $\operatorname{IBr}(X\mid Q)$ is given by the definition (Definition 4.1) where the notation is first used.
It gives a long list of conditions that constitute what it means for the inductive BAW condition to hold for a simple group $S$ and a prime $p$. The first of these is that there should exist subsets $\operatorname{IBr}(X\mid Q)\subseteq\operatorname{IBr}(X)$ satisfying certain properties.
So this is not referring to subsets that have already been defined. Verifying the inductive BAW condition for a particular $S$ and $p$ would entail finding such subsets.
I didn't find the notation $\operatorname{IBr}(b\mid Q)$, but I would imagine something similar applies there.

ok, great. It starts making sense now. Thanks
